# I am getting jqXHR.status === 0 error while making ajax request in android 9

Tags: cordova

I am making an ajax request in android 9 in cordova app. The request is working fine in previous versions of android but showing jqXHR.status == 0 in 9. Please help me with this

Comment: do you see any errors??

Comment: Yes it is going into ajax error function and I am getting jqXHR.status == 0

Comment: try setting `android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"` in your manifest file. Android 9 requires this for xhr requets.

Comment: I have set android:usesCleartextTraffic="true" in my AndroidManifest.xml but I am still getting same error